# Documentation on which sub-features are included for a given WindowsFeature

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-dsc

We are in the process of setting up [PowerShell DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview) for the dev/test/production environments for a new project. With the obvious goal that all environments end up identical.

One example is using the [WindowsFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/windowsfeatureresource) resource to install the `Web-Server` feature. This will install the Web-Server feature, together with some of its sub-features.

**What I'm looking for is some proper documentation on *which* sub-features will be installed automatically. So that I'm able to identify which additional sub-features we require that also needs to be installed manually.**

I can of course check locally which sub-features will be installed by default:

```
PS C:\> Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -WhatIf
What if: Continue with installation?
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Web Server (IIS)".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Web Server".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Common HTTP Features".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Default Document".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Directory Browsing".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] HTTP Errors".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Static Content".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Health and Diagnostics".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] HTTP Logging".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Performance".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Static Content Compression".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Security".
What if: Performing installation for "[Web Server (IIS)] Request Filtering".
What if: The target server may need to be restarted after the installation completes.

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    Maybe          Success        {Web Server (IIS), Web Server, Common HTTP...
```

But can I trust that this will be the same result on all servers? And is this something which is set in stone, or is it subject to change at some time?

Or will my safest bet be to explicitly specify each and every single sub-feature in my DSC script?

Comment: Your best bet is always being explicit.  This is ideally something you set once, so the initial overhead doesn't matter.  You can see if there is documentation on github for DSC or something of that nature.

Comment: [Enable DSC feature doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/windowsfeatureresource). Looks like it does rely on the `*-WindowsFeature` cmdlets.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: _"Your best bet is always being explicit."_ I absolutely agree. However, even though this will be mostly a "do once then forget" thing, it will be easier for the next guy picking up the project to see one single WindowsFeature resource for _Web-Server_, with a few additions, than 15+ entries... But given the lack of more feedback on the question it looks like there isn't any good alternative. Thanks :-)